# js/jquery scrolling to bottom of div when the page is loaded (IE problem)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My codes works perfectly on Firefox. It works on IE when the content of the div is less, it fail to scroll to bottom when the content of div is too high in IE. Button click to scroll to bottom has no problem, but page reloaded to scroll to bottom has the problem. How to fix the IE problem? how to scroll to bottom of div when the page is loaded on IE? Below is my codes, you can copy paste directly to test it. :

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function asd(){
d = document.getElementById('div');d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight;
// $('#div').scrollTop($('#div')[0].scrollHeight);
}
</script>

<button onclick="d = document.getElementById('div');d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight;">scroll-div</button>

<div id='div' style=' overflow:scroll; height:300px; width:200px; border:1px solid blue; background:blue;'>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
asd();
</script>
```

Comment: ARRRRRG NEVER PUT CODE DIRECTLY IN EVENTS!! USE FUNCTIONS!!!! e: sorry... but that IE problem needs a patch. Besides: your first address for jQuery issues should be what? [jQuery!](http://plugins.jquery.com/content/ie-7-scroll-height-sometimes-broken)

Comment: Which version of IE does the problem occur in?

Comment: what events? I did use function asd(); Since when I use events? Why don't use events?

Comment: Wegginho is referring to your use of the `onclick` attribute on your BUTTON, instead of adding the event from the JavaScript (which is the recommended way of doing it). Don't mind his mention of it -- it's irrelevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: @DavidJCobb, IE7. <body onload="asd()"> is work!! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait until the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){asd();});
```

Putting an instruction somewhere at the end of the document doesn't be the same like waiting for the ready-event.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me, I use $('#div').ready(function(){asd();}); to wait until the contents of div are finish loaded.

Comment: jQuery doesn't care about the selector #div , ready is always bound to document.

Comment: document is mean whole page? If the page has 10 divs. Each divs also has lots of contents, it will wait for all 10 divs are finish loaded? Anyway to make it wait for a particular div only?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` will wait for the entire DOM to be loaded. Note, this does not mean that the page is visible at this point, just that the browser knows what elements are going to be rendered and roughly where they will appear in the page. You could attach an event to a specific element being ready, but there is no point as the time saved will be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the call to `asd()` after the DOM has been loaded. I know putting it at the bottom of the page should do this, but it cannot be relied on.

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function asd(){
        var d = document.getElementById('div');
        d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight;
    }

    $(function() {
        asd(); // scroll div on load
        $("#button".click(function() {
            asd(); // scroll div on click
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="button">scroll-div</button>

<div id='div' style=' overflow:scroll; height:300px; width:200px; border:1px solid blue; background:blue;'>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
        <p>asdasdas</p><p>asdasdas</p>
</div>
```

Comment: May I know what is mean by $(function() ? Is it mean "DOM has been loaded" ?

Comment: It is the shorthand version of `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. There are some minor differences, but it can be used 99% of the time without problem.

Comment: I need to show messages when the page is loaded, $(function() { showMsg(); asd(); }); How to wait until showMsg() finish render the contents before execute asd()? I have jQuery.get(); .append(); .replace(); .innerHTML inside showMsg()

Comment: If showMsg() is executed BEFORE the DOM is ready, and if asd() is executed AFTER DOM is ready (at this point all messages are rendered already), so the problem is fix. But now my situation is AFTER the DOM is ready, all messages still not yet finish rendered, because showMsg() and asd() are executed only AFTER the DOM is ready, "executed" doesn't mean "finish rendered".