# how to use jquery wait until innerHTML finish loaded before execute other function?

Tags: jquery

I try to get data from database and display them onto a div, after all messages are shown on the div, then only it will know the scrollheight of the div, it will auto scroll to the bottom of div as default by function asd(). My problem is when there are too many messages on database, it took very long time to display them all onto the div, so asd() executed before all messages are displayed. Meaning the scrollheight of the div is incorrect at this point, thus auto scroll to bottom is fail.

```
$(function() { showMsg(); asd(); });
```

How to wait until `showMsg()` finish render the contents before execute `asd()`? I have `jQuery.get(); .append(); .replace(); .innerHTML` inside showMsg().

The problem is fixed when I use timeout to execute asd() after 3 seconds :

```
$(function() { showMsg(); setTimeout(asd();, 3000); });
```

That's why I sure asd() is executed when showMsg() is not yet finish loaded the contents.

I guess I know where is the problem. If showMsg() is executed BEFORE the DOM is ready, and if asd() is executed AFTER DOM is ready (at this point all messages are rendered already), so the problem is fix. But now my situation is AFTER the DOM is ready, all messages still not yet finish rendered, because showMsg() and asd() are executed only AFTER the DOM is ready, "executed" doesn't mean "finish rendered". How to make sure showMsg() finish rendered the contents into a div before execute asd() ?

For those who want to know the codes inside showMsg(), here :

```
function showMsg(){
    jQuery.get("showRspContentLive.php", function(data) {
       $('#rsp .rspcontent').append(data);
       var container = document.getElementById("rsp2");
       var text = container.innerHTML;          
       text = text.replace(/\(smile1\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/smile1.gif" border="0" />')
       .replace(/\(smile2\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/smile2.gif" border="0" />')
       .replace(/\(smile3\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/smile3.gif" border="0" />')
       .replace(/\(haha2\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/haha2.gif" border="0" />')
       .replace(/\(haha3\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/haha3.gif" border="0" />')
       .replace(/\(haha5\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/haha5.gif" border="0" />')
       .replace(/\(sad1\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/sad1.gif" border="0" />');
       container.innerHTML = text;

       $('#rsp').scrollTop($('#rsp')[0].scrollHeight); // this is my asd() function, how to execute it only if after container.innerHTML=text; is finish loaded?   
    }); 
};
```

Comment: why don't you bind an event to your rendered content instead?

Comment: how to bind an event to my rendered content?

Answer (score 3):

you mean like

```
$.get("http://someurl.com", 
    function(html){
        //format the data any way you would like...
        //...

        //setm the html
        $('#myCt').html(html);

        //call your function after
        asd();
});

var asd = function(){
    //some cool stuff
}
```

**Update**
*If you're not making any AJAX requests in your `asd()` function then your `showMsg()` function should update just fine, otherwise just chain your `callbacks`*...
e.g. `$.get('moredata.aspx', asd);`

Comment: your codes is similar to the codes inside my showMsg() function, please refer to my updated question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: oh cool this got +3 already.  I updated my answer for you.  It should still work in the order that you're shooting for.  the key is in the `callbacks`.

Comment: I have tested ur codes, it doesn't solve my problem. The key is "executed" doesn't mean "finish rendered". You execute $('#myCt').html(html); before execute asd(); but if html has lot of contents, it will take very very long time to render them. asd() will still be executed before they are finish rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Use `asd` in the callback to `jQuery.get`:

```
function showMsg() {
   jQuery.get("http://example.com", function(data) { 
       // Your code that uses .append(), .replace(), and .innerHTML
       asd();
   });
}
```

This will automatically call `asd` once your `get` finishes executing. So you don't need to explicitly call `asd` in the `load` handler:

```
$(function() { 
   showMsg(); 
});
```

Comment: i have tested it, IE can't finish render the contents of showMsg() before execute asd() when the contents is too much. Actually this question is expanded from my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056010/js-jquery-scrolling-to-bottom-of-div-when-the-page-is-loaded-ie-problem

Comment: @zac1987 that doesn't seem right. How are you inserting `data` into the DOM?

Comment: I have show the inserting data method onto my question, thank you.

Comment: I guess I know where is the problem. If showMsg() is executed BEFORE the DOM is ready, and if asd() is executed AFTER DOM is ready (at this point all messages are rendered already), so the problem is fix. But now my situation is AFTER the DOM is ready, all messages still not yet finish rendered, because showMsg() and asd() are executed only AFTER the DOM is ready, "executed" doesn't mean "finish rendered".